# Sklearn's TargetEncoder not dealing properly with category with 1 observation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Given this piece of code

```
from category_encoders import TargetEncoder

X = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c"]
y = [5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 4]
encoder = TargetEncoder(smoothing = 0, min_samples_leaf = 0)
print(encoder.fit_transform(X, y))
```

I would expect the output to be

```
[5, 5, 5, 6.5, 6.5, 4]
```

But for some reason it returns

```
[5, 5, 5, 6.5, 6.5, 5.333]
```

That is, category 'c' is being encoded to 5.33 which is the average of all the values.

My question is: shouldn't the category 'c' be encoded to 4, since I set no smoothing and no min_samples_leaf?

Same result happens when min_samples_leaf = 1 and/or smoothing > 0. No matter which value of smoothing I set, category 'c' is always transformed to the global mean.

I'm using v2.5.0 of category_encoders.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the version used.

I've upgraded it to the latest (2.6.0) and now it works.

In particular, to get just the mean (without regularization) I had to set up:

```
encoder = TargetEncoder(smoothing=0, min_samples_leaf=0)
```

And by using some smoothing it still works as expected, it does not just return the global average.